# Error while reading shared library symbols for /lib/ld-linux.so.2

Tags: 11.10, gdb

When I try and run these commands (in order):

```
gdb -tui main
layout regs
b main
r
s
```

It gives me a ton of errors on the 'r' command, giving the error in the title, so I can't even debug my program. It's nothing complex, just a main.c file, a Makefile, an asm.h and asm.s (hence layout regs). If I run these commands on a Slax VM, they work perfectly. Why doesn't Ubuntu 11.10 work then?

P.S. The output is this:

```
Error in re-setting breakpoint 1: Register 41 is not available
Error while reading shared library symbols for /lib/ld-linux.so.2:
Register 41 is not available
Error while reading shared library symbols for /lib/ld-linux.so.2:
Register 41 is not available
[Inferior 1 (process 1844) exited normally]
```

Comment: First, I doubt this is Ubuntu specific, and you might be better off on StackOverflow.  Also, I think you need to post the actual source.  It is an interesting question.  My guess is your Makefile or asm.s are breaking shared library loading.